# Get SVN buildnumber of specific branch in Maven

Tags: java, maven, svn

I am using SVN . Here is my repo structure

```
root revision no - 400 
root/product1/trunk revision no - 300
root/product1/branch1 revision no - 310 
root/product1/branch2 revision no - 320


root/product2/trunk revision no - 200
root/product2/branch1 revision no - 210
.......
```

I have configured below maven plugin under product1/branch1

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>buildnumber-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.4</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <phase>validate</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>create</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
    <configuration>
        <doCheck>false</doCheck>
        <doUpdate>false</doUpdate>
        <scmDirectory></scmDirectory>
        <useLastCommittedRevision>true</useLastCommittedRevision>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

i am getting `buildNumber` as 400 though i expect it as 310 i.e per specific to branch or trunk. I know revisions are global revisions from root
not from specific branch/trunk.

Can we configure it to set specific branch ? If not possible is there any other maven plugin that can help here ?

Comment: Does [`scmBranchPropertyName`](http://www.mojohaus.org/buildnumber-maven-plugin/create-mojo.html#scmBranchPropertyName) not do this? Something like `<scmBranchPropertyName>product1/branch1</scmBranchPropertyName>`

Comment: No difference. As per documentation  `scmBranchPropertyName` is  for `You can rename the buildScmBranch property name to another 
 property name if desired.`.